# Connecting table to jtextbox

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, view

I am trying to connect every table field in my jtextbox but when i run this code it says syntax error. I am using sqlite and netbeans I hope you can help me

```
 try{

        String sql="Select * From account where id=txtId.getText() AND fname=txtFname.getText() AND lname=txtLname.getText() AND username=txtUsername.getText() AND password=txtPassword.getText()";

        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, txtId.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txtFname.getText());
        pst.setString(3, txtLname.getText());
        pst.setString(4, txtUsername.getText());
        pst.setString(5, txtPassword.getText());

        pst.execute();
        rs.close();
        pst.close();

    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
    finally{
        try{
            rs.close();
            pst.close();

        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }

}
```

Comment: No we cant. We cant understand what your problem is.

Comment: @LittleChild My problem is I want to view all my data in my database and that data will be shown in the jtextfield

Comment: JTextField will be very small. Consider using a JTextArea

Comment: @LittleChild the error is "java.sql.SQLEXCEPTION:near "(":Syntax error"

Comment: See my answer. Start using PreparedStatement

Answer (score 1):

Try putting placeholders(?) in your query..

```
String sql="Select * From account where id=? AND fname=? AND lname=? AND username=? AND password=?";
```

you are providing values but there are no place holders in your query:
`pst.setString(1, txtId.getText());`

**Edit1: Reply to your comment**

```
try{
    String sql="Select * From account where id=? AND fname=? AND lname=? AND username=? AND password=?";
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, txtId.getText());
    pst.setString(2, txtFname.getText());
    pst.setString(3, txtLname.getText());
    pst.setString(4, txtUsername.getText());
    pst.setString(5, txtPassword.getText());

    rs=pst.execute(); //to get resultset
    while(rs.next())
    {
      //Do what you want to do if the records are found
      System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
      System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
    }
}
catch(SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}
finally{
    try{
        if(rs!=null)rs.close();
        if(pst!=null)pst.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
}
```

Comment: where will i put this? will I make an another class or i will put this to my main class?

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto You can replace your existing code(which you have put in your question) with this code.

Comment: i put that code in window opened event but it didn't work at all

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto can you share your code, so that we might be able to figure out the problem. [My guess is that you must put the code in button click event to get the parameters from text-box. Your code might not have been getting parameters on window open event from text-box.]

Answer (score 0):

You are making method calls inside a String literal. The simplest way is to move your method calls out of your String and get the return value in variables. You can then append these to your query String.

The correct way would be to use PreparedStatement. It is designed for situations like these. Tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Update:
Since you are using PreparedStatement, replace any unknown values in the query with a ? . Then you can set them later using the appropriate setter.